# Apache migrate sites

Tags: migration, apache-2.4, website

I have to migrate all sites from a server to another.
The actual apache2 server configuration is a virtual host for each site and this is working.
My problem is that I want to migrate all sites to the new machine, test that everything is working then change dns.
So by now I have only a machine with a public IP no domain associated, how can I configure apache2 to run multiple server on a machine like this?

Answer (score 0):

If all the virtual hosts are without SSL, you could connect the server with `nc` or `telnet` and test

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

(or even `GET`) for every host needed and see whether you got the correct response. I'm using this since I find it easiest, but probably most would like to experience this with a browser.

To be able to test with a web browser you could add there hostnames to your local configuration `hosts` file. Just add a line for every hostname you want to test, e.g.

```
192.168.0.1      example.com
192.168.0.1      example.net
192.168.0.1      example.org
```

The location of the `hosts` file varies and you must flush dns cache afterwards.

- Linux & similar: `/etc/hosts`
- Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` & restart `dnsclient` service after
- Mac OS X: edit `/private/etc/hosts` & reload with `dscacheutil -flushcache`